# Xamarin: Passar dados do item selecionado em um ListView para outra Tela

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Como faço para passar os dados selecionados de uma tela para outra em Xamarin?

Tenho um ListView que recebe as informações de uma Api e quero que o usuário ao clicar no item, visualize essas informações em uma outra tela, abaixo o codigo do click

```
   private async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
                if(e.SelectedItem !=null)
                {
                    var selection = e.SelectedItem as UltimasNoticias;
                    //DisplayAlert("Você Selecionou", selection.Post_title, "ok");                         
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new PostView());
                    #region DisabledSelectionHighlighting
                    // ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
                    #endregion
                } 

     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode passá-los através do construtor da página, por exemplo:

```
private async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.SelectedItem !=null)
    {
        var selection = e.SelectedItem as UltimasNoticias;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new PostView(selection));
        #region DisabledSelectionHighlighting
        ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
        #endregion
    } 
}
```

No codebehind você poderia tratar assim:

```
public class PostView : ContentPage
{
    PostViewModel viewModel = null;

    public PostView() : this(new UltimasNoticias())
    {

    }

    public PostView(UltimasNoticias dados)
    {
        InitializeComponents();

        // Aqui você usa o parâmetro para entregar para sua ViewModel ou o que quer que seja
        viewModel = new PostViewModel(dados);

        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: valeu ajudou obrigado!